# Handling conflicts between "sorbet-typed" and "gems" RBI files

Tags: sorbet

I've installed Sorbet in a Rails codebase and am seeing many instances of the following error:

```
sorbet/rbi/sorbet-typed/lib/activerecord/all/activerecord.rbi:958:
Method ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition#column redefined without matching argument count. Expected: 3, got: 5 https://srb.help/4010
     958 |  def column(
     959 |    name,
     960 |    type,
     961 |    index: nil,
     962 |    default: nil,
     963 |    **options
     964 |  ); end
    sorbet/rbi/gems/activerecord.rbi:5256: Previous definition
    5256 |  def column(name, type, **options); end
```

To make the type errors go away, I either have to change `typed: true` to `typed: false` in one of the files (which excludes some of the types that *don't* overlap), or I have to manually go in and delete/comment out the overlapping methods (which is time-consuming and brittle).

I'm wondering if there's some sort of programmatic solution, where I can say "in case of conflict, use the method with higher arity" or "always choose the sorbet-typed definition."

Again this is in a Rails codebase but I imagine this would exist for any conflict between the hand-generated and auto-generated RBIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some of these methods, unfortunately since "Shapes" (Sorbet's experimental implementation of typeable Hashes) don't allow optional keys, they can't be used to represent these methods accurately. As a result, the arity of a lot of methods - especially complex stuff in Rails - is different between sorbet-typed and sorbet's autogenerated files.

I've just been using `srb rbi suggest-typed` to automatically set the typedness of files in my repo, and it just marks those as false. As far as I can tell, the type information from sorbet-typed is still used even if the file is marked as false (though I should probably look into that more to verify that that's the case).

Unfortunately I don't have a better solution for the problem at the moment, but just using suggest-typed seems to be sufficient for me so far.